# Python behavior of classes that have nested classes

Tags: python, inheritance, inner-classes

I have a number of factory objects that look like the following:

```
class OperatorFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Operator
        sqlalchemy_session = Session()
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = 'commit'

    operator = 'equals'
```

They all share that same `Meta` inner class and have distinct models, but they also share those `sqlalchemy_session` and `sqlalchemy_session_persistence` lines.

My question is, is it possible to write this object in a more DRY (don't repeat yourself) fashion where I don't have to constantly include the lines `sqlalchemy_session = Session()` and `sqlalchemy_session_persistence = 'commit'`?

So far I have at least a dozen factories and it's getting repetitive.

Comment: write a function to define the meta class and say `Meta = generate_meta(model=Operator, ...)` inside each?  (I am unfamiliar with sql alchemy, there may be a way it supports that is easier)

Comment: Unless I'm misreading wouldn't `Meta` just need to be a base class and have all factories inherit off it?

Comment: @BTables I assume `Session()` must be called for each meta class, in which case it is a little more complicated but that may actually be a bug where they should all have the same session object that would be fixed by using a base class.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen It could indeed be an organizational thing. If `Session()` needs to be called for every instance of `Meta` that could still be achieved via a base class with the call inside `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what sessions you want to be shared, [the only documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/orms.html#managing-sessions) I could find talks about sharing sessions between all factories but you are generating a separate session for each factory class **but not for every instance**. (it is a class variable so it is shared between all instances)

Assuming this was an oversight and you actually want a single session for all `Meta` fields, you would create a base class for the Meta class:

```py
class BaseMeta:
    # now this sessions is shared between ALL factories
    sqlalchemy_session = Session()
    sqlalchemy_session_persistence = 'commit'

class OperatorFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta(BaseMeta):
        model = Operator

    operator = 'equals'
```

alternatively if you want each class to have their own session then you may want a factory function for your meta class of your factory class.

```py
def generate_meta_options(model_):
    class Meta:
        model = model_
        sqlalchemy_session = Session()
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = 'commit'
    return Meta

class OperatorFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    Meta = generate_meta_options(Operator)
    operator = 'equals'
```

If the intention is instead to have a separate session for every instance I'm not sure what should be done, I can't figure the relevant documentation on how the factory objects are instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `Meta` as an inner-class you can make it a base class and just have factories inherit off it. As you've said they have distinct models you can simply provide a parameter for that to `__init__`. Take the following for example:

```
class Meta:
    def __init__(self, Operator):
        model = Operator
        sqlalchemy_session = Session()
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = 'commit'

class Factory1(Meta, factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        op = 'equals'
        super.__init__(op)

class Factory2(Meta, factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        op = 'lessthan'
        super.__init__(op)
```